# Сохранение html из webview

Tags: android, html, java, webview, css

Здравствуйте. У меня есть webview, в которую загружаются страницы html. Мне необходимо реализовать сохранение некоторых страниц в external storage для последующего офлайн просмотра. Страницы должны сохраняться вместе с css, изображениями и т.д. Как это лучше реализовать?

P.S. Пример. Пользователь просматривает страницу, нажимает добавить в избранное. После этого он может зайти в раздел "Избранное" приложения и прочитать еще раз эту статью без подключения к интернету.

Answer (score 1):

Есть [такой](https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader) проект.

[Тут](https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader/blob/master/src/com/hyperionics/war_test/MyActivity.java) пример использования.

```
public void saveArchive(String fileName){
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Hyperionics/");
            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            webView.saveWebArchive(dir.toString() + File.separator + fileName);
            //mWebView.saveWebArchive(filename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
```